# Method overload. How the compiler decide which to use?

Tags: c#, logging

I have 2 methods.

```
    1. public void Log(object tolog, string Instance)
    2. public void Log(params object[] tolog)
```

And I call Log like this, where tolog1 is a object

```
Log(tolog1,"Hello")
```

I'm confused as to why the compiler has chosen the second overload. What conditions would cause this?

Comment: @Christos: I thought so, but the compiler show me it using the second one

Comment: It will definitely use `Log(object tolog, string Instance)` how come the compiler is showing you that it is using the second one ?

Comment: good post by Eric Lippert: http://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/

Comment: @user3398315: If the compiler is saying it wants to favour the `params` overload, are you using any inheritance here? That is, are both methods declared in the same level of class hierarchy?

Answer (score 3):

Your call `Log(tolog1,"Hello")` would use the method `Log(object tolog, string Instance)` that is because of [Overloading Resolution Rules (7.4.2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Given the list of arguments your first method overload  `Log(object tolog, string Instance)` is a more suitable/closer candidate and compiler can determine that because of the rules specified:

[Overloading Resolution Rules (7.4.2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> - Given the set of applicable candidate function members, the best    function member in that set is located.
> - If the set contains only one function member, then that function    member is the best function member.
> - Otherwise, the best function member is the one **function member that  is better than all other function members with respect to the given argument list, provided that each function member is compared to all**   other function members using the rules in [Section 7.4.2.2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691338%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).
> - If there is not exactly one function member that is better than all    other function members, then the function member invocation is
>     ambiguous and a compile-time error occurs

Under [Section 7.4.2.2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691338%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) You will see:

> Given an argument list A with a set of argument types {A1, A2, ...,
>   AN} and two applicable function members MP and MQ with parameter types
>   {P1, P2, ..., PN} and {Q1, Q2, ..., QN}, MP is defined to be a better
>   function member than MQ if
>
> - for each argument, the implicit conversion from AX to PX is not worse    than the implicit conversion from AX to QX, and
> - for at least one argument, the conversion from AX to PX is better    than the conversion from AX to QX.
>
> When performing this evaluation, if MP or MQ is applicable in its
>   expanded form, then PX or QX refers to a parameter in the expanded
>   form of the parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the compiler chooses the type which is closer i.e. the object that is at highest level of Hierarchy / Inheritance.

In your case, `Log(tolog1,"Hello")`, `tolog1` satisfies both the overloads

`Log(params object[] tolog)` and `Log(object tolog, string Instance)` but in case of second parameter `"Hello"` the compiler chooses `Log(object tolog, string Instance)` As `System.String` is closer to "Hello" than `System.Object`